# How can I get Enum fields names using reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

This is my class:

```
public enum Currency {
    NIS, USD, EUR, GBP, JPY, AUD, CAD, DKK, NOK, ZAR, SEK, CHF, JOD, LBP, EGP;

    private String name;
    private int unit;
    private String country;
    private double rate;
    private double change;
}
```

When I tried to get the fields names of this class using reflection I got the private fields and the enum constants (NIS,EUR,....)

How can I get only the private fields names?

Comment: Huh? Enums have been carrying methods since 1.6 at least

Comment: @kolossus since they were introduced actually: Java 5.

Comment: Your fields don't have any values, so why do you want to access them? If you're planning on setting the values through reflection run-time, you might want to reconsider your design. Enums should be compile-time constants.

Comment: Whats wrong with adding ordinary *getters* for your fields?

Comment: The enum code seems to be incomplete, the constructor and access methods are missing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37632/1754020

Comment: Get the fields and pick out the ones you want with `Field.getModifiers()`. (Though I suspect you might want every field that isn't an enum constant, rather than just the private fields, so you might want `Field.isEnumConstant()`.)

Comment: I want to get the names of the fields. I edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE

From your comment, try the following.  It also does not pick up any `public` fields if you were to have any.

```
    Field[] allFields = Currency.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : allFields) {
        if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
            System.out.println(field.getName());
        }
    }
```

Results:

[image]

To get rid of the $VALUES from the result check if the field is not synthetic

```
    Field[] allFields = Currency.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : allFields) {
        if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers()) && !field.isSynthetic()) {
            System.out.println(field.getName());
        }
    }
```

Results:

[image]

As far as giving values to these fields and accessing them you don't need to do reflection to do this.  You just need to define the fields appropriately with each enum as followed.

```
public enum Currency {
    NIS("Name1", 0, "NIS", 1, 2), 
    USD("Name2", 1, "USD", 1, 2), 
    EUR("Name3", 2, "EUR", 1, 2), 
    GBP("Name4", 3, "GBP", 1, 2), 
    JPY("Name5", 4, "JPY", 1, 2), 
    AUD("Name6", 5, "AUD", 1, 2), 
    CAD("Name7", 6, "CAD", 1, 2), 
    DKK("Name8", 7, "DKK", 1, 2), 
    NOK("Name9", 8, "NOK", 1, 2), 
    ZAR("Name10", 9, "ZAR", 1, 2), 
    SEK("Name11", 10, "SEK", 1, 2), 
    CHF("Name12", 11, "CHF", 1, 2), 
    JOD("Name13", 12, "JOD", 1, 2), 
    LBP("Name14", 13, "LBP", 1, 2), 
    EGP("Name15", 14, "EGP", 1, 2);

    private final String name;
    private final int unit;
    private final String country;
    private final double rate;
    private final double change;

    private Currency(String name, int unit, String country, double rate, double change) {
        this.name = name;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.country = country;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.change = change;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public double getChange() {
        return change;
    }
}
```

The usage of this would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (Currency currency : Currency.values()) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + currency.getName());
        System.out.println("Unit: " + currency.getUnit());
        System.out.println("Country: " + currency.getCountry());
        System.out.println("Rate: " + currency.getRate());
        System.out.println("Change: " + currency.getChange());
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Results (Not all results are displayed):

[image]

Or you can directly use an enum as followed:

```
System.out.println(Currency.AUD.getName() + " " + Currency.AUD.getCountry());
```

Result:

> Name6 AUD

Answer (score 3):

Try test [Field.isEnumConstant()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#isEnumConstant%28%29)

Also you can check `getModifiers()` and test if it's static, private, etc.

Also `isSynthetic()` might be needed for testing too.

Comment: Your answer is better :)

Comment: @JuanLopes my answer is not complete; you should probably restore and tweak your answer a little bit, so that we have a real answer here.

Comment: @AlexKapustian: [Are you just using us to read the documentation for you? Because if you looked at the documentation, you would see `Field.getName()`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getName--)

Answer (score 1):

This code should do it (based on bayou.io's answer):

```
List<String> fields = Arrays.stream(Currency.class.getDeclaredFields())
        .filter(x -> !x.isEnumConstant() && !x.isSynthetic())
        .map(x -> x.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It just iterates all the fields, filtering the ones that aren't enum constants nor synthetic (like the `$VALUES` field).

Comment: they do have an obscure method in `Field` for that:) I wonder how it's implemented though.

Comment: Yes, but it misses the field "$VALUES".

Comment: use `isSynthetic()` can probably filter it out

Comment: The OP only wants the private field names.  This does not work if there are public field names in the enum.